# Why do we neglect the exclamation point when assigning a value to an optional in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

In this code, we initialize an optional `UIWindow?`. To assign it a value, I would assume that I would assign the value to `self.window!`, since that is where the value of the optional resides. But as you can see, we need to use `self.window`. Why is this the case. Why does the first line under the comment not look like `self.window! = UIWindow(frame: ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exclamation point is used to *force unwrap* optional values. In your code, `window` is not yet defined and trying to force unwrap it will throw an error.

From [The Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

> Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.

Comment: Further, the statement in question is an assignment, so the current value of self.window is immaterial - after the statement is executed it will be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a non-optional to an optional; that is the way to initialize an optional with a non`-nil` value.

An `Optional<T>` is implemented as an enum with cases `None` (created by assigning `nil`), and `Some (T)` (created by assigning a value of type `T`).